# Drop down list isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

Controller:

```
   OnePersonAllInfoViewModel vModel = new OnePersonAllInfoViewModel();
  vModel.PreferredContactType = new PreferredContactType();


ViewBag.PrefContactTypes = new SelectList(dbEntities.PreferredContactTypes
                                  .OrderBy(pct => pct.PreferredContactTypeID),
                                   "PreferredContactTypeID", "PreferredContactType1",
                                   vModel.PreferredContactType.PreferredContactTypeID);
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PreferredContactType.PreferredContactTypex)
    </div>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PreferredContactType.PreferredContactTypeID, 
       ViewBag.PrefContactTypes as SelectList)
```

And I get this error on post back... There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'PreferredContactType.PreferredContactTypeID'

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: On postback have you rebind the viewModel with data? This error should mean that vModel.PreferredContactType is null (and is normal if you execute a postaback and return the same page after save changes or validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HttpPost controller action you must repopulate the `ViewBag.PrefContactTypes` property the same way you did in your GET action if you redisplay the same view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(OnePersonAllInfoViewModel model)
{
    ViewBag.PrefContactTypes = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

Also you seem to have defined some class that is suffixed with ViewModel. This leaves the reader to believe that you are using view models in your application and in the very next line you use `ViewBag`. Why? Why not take full advantage of the view model and its strong typing?

Just like this:

```
public class OnePersonAllInfoViewModel
{
     public int PreferredContactTypeID { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<PreferredContactType> PrefContactTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your GET action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new OnePersonAllInfoViewModel();
    model.PrefContactTypes = dbEntities
        .PreferredContactTypes
        .OrderBy(pct => pct.PreferredContactTypeID)
        .ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

then the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.PreferredContactTypeID, 
    Model.PrefContactTypes
)
```

and the POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OnePersonAllInfoViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model is invalid => we must redisplay the same view =>
        // ensure that the PrefContactTypes property is populated
        model.PrefContactTypes = dbEntities
            .PreferredContactTypes
            .OrderBy(pct => pct.PreferredContactTypeID)
            .ToList();
        return View(model); 
    }

    // the model is valid => use the model.PreferredContactTypeID to do some
    // processing and redirect
    ...

    // Obviously if you need to stay on the same view then you must ensure that 
    // you have populated the PrefContactTypes property of your view model because
    // the view requires it in order to successfully render the dropdown list.
    // In this case you could simply move the code that populates this property
    // outside of the if statement that tests the validity of the model

    return RedirectToAction("Success"); 
}
```